# Show rows with at least one occurrence in a relation table?

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, group-by, having

I have the following table schema:

```
user (id, name, alias, password, active, mail, age)
comment(id, news(FK), user(FK), text, date)
new_cat(news(FK), category(FK))
```

I'm trying to select all the users who have commented on AT LEAST one `new` of EVERY `category`.

This is what I'm trying without any success:

```
SELECT * FROM user AS u, comment AS c
WHERE u.id = c.user AND c.news IN (SELECT news FROM new_cat);
```

I believe this is not iterating properly and checking for EVERY `category` and just checks if the condition applies just on one `category`.

How can I properly do this?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? that really help

Comment: `,`  was an older syntax `CROSS JOIN` I would use `JOIN` to connect two tables which support by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-92

Comment: You have noted the column `category` of `new_cat` as a FK. Is there a table where you store all the categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the tables, group by user and set the condition in the `HAVING` clause.

If there is a `category` table where you store all the categories:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM user u
INNER JOIN comment c ON c.user = u.id
INNER JOIN new_cat n ON n.news = c.news
GROUP BY u.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT n.category) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM category);
```